# How can the axioms (and primitives) of Tarski's axiomatization of $\Bbb R$ be independent?

Tags: logic, model-theory, real-numbers, axioms

While reading through [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axiomatization_of_the_reals) about Tarski's axiomatization of the reals, a particular bit of text jumped out at me:

> Tarski proved these 8 axioms and 4 primitive notions independent.

This raised two questions in my mind, after a bit of thought.

First of all, I wondered how one could prove a primitive notion independent from *anything*, as it doesn't seem to carry any sort of logical content with it.

Second of all, it seemed that one of the axioms was impossible to separate from another. Namely:

> **Axiom 7**: $1\in\Bbb R$
>
> **Axiom 8**: $1<1+1$

Given that $+$ is assumed only to be an operation on $\Bbb R$ and $<$ is assumed only to be a relation on $\Bbb R,$ I can't imagine how Axiom 8 can fail to imply Axiom 7. I've attempted to rephrase the axioms (and have made them a bit more satisfactory on a personal level), but I cannot see a way to alleviate this.

For those who are curious, I have managed to prove that none of the following axioms is implied by the rest of the axioms: 1,2,3,5,6,8. I'd like to play with Axiom 4 a while longer, so please don't give hints about that, unless it's necessary to answer me.

Comment: I think that your perplexity is about Ax.7... The independence of Ax.8 can be showed - I think - building a model with only one element. See Alfred Tarski, Introduction to Logic and to the Methodology of the Deductive Sciences (4th ed - 1994), page 204 : we can replace it adding the symbol "$0$" and the axiom : $0 < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See :

- Alfred Tarski, [Introduction to Logic and to the Methodology of the Deductive Sciences](https://books.google.it/books?id=vtzCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA202) (4th ed Oxford - 1994; original edition : 1936), page 202 (Dover reprint : page 214).

A preliminary comment : the axioms are second-order logic; thus the interpretation of the set $R$ is not (necessarily) the *domain* of the model.

The first six axioms can be satisfied in an empty domain; thus, Axiom 7 is needed to ensure that $R$ is not empty.

Axiom 8 is needed in order enusere that $1$ is not the only object in $R$; see Tarski page 204 [Dover reprint : 216] : we can replace it adding the symbol "$0$" and the axiom : $0<1$.

We have to specify that $1 \in R$ because otherwise we can have a model with an empty $R$ and an object $1$ "external" to it.

---

Regarding the independence of the primitive notions, see [Padoa's method](http://wilfridhodges.co.uk/history06.pdf), or see Tarski, page 184 [Dover reprint : 194].

Comment: Regarding your preliminary comment, do you mean that $<$ may be a relation on more than just $R$?

Comment: Incidentally, when I proved axiom 8 wasn't implied by the others, I took $R=\{1\},$ $<$ the equality relation, and $+$ to be multiplication.

Comment: @CameronBuie - yes; a model of the theory is a set $R$ and an element $1$. I think that, if we omit axioms 7&8, all the other axioms can be satisfied with $R=\emptyset$ and $1$ "outside" $R$.

Comment: So, if we let $R$ be the empty set, let $+$ and $<$ be the addition operation and order relation on $\omega,$ say, then we've satisfied all but axiom 7?

Comment: @CameronBuie - I think so; all the axioms 1-6 are vacuously true for the elements of $R$...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Wikepedia/Tarski mentions Ucsnay work found here https://vdocuments.site/a-note-on-tarskis-note.html I find theorem 5 strange - closure of addition. Looks like $r + t$ at the start doesn't have to be in $R$.